# Combining the values of different rows into one single row in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df like this:

```
head(freq_patch)
  Patch Morphotype.ID freq
1    75             0    1
2    75             4    1
3    75             6    3
4    75             7    3
5    80            11    1
6    80            12    1`
```

I wanted to transform the column Morphotype.ID into columns. The frequencies (freq) would be then values for  the columns in each row. I wanted to have one row per patch.

I did the following:

```
freq_patch %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  spread(Morphotype.ID, freq) %>%
  select(-rn)`
```

And I obtained:

```
head(freq_patch)
Patch   `0`   `1`   `3`   `4`   `6`   `7`   `8`   `9`  `11`  `12`
  <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1    75     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
2    75    NA    NA    NA     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
3    75    NA    NA    NA    NA     3    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
4    75    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     3    NA    NA    NA    NA
5    80    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     1    NA
6    80    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     1`
```

Does anyone know how I could group by patch and replace NAs by 0, please?

```
Patch   `0`   `1`   `3`   `4`   `6`   `7`   `8`   `9`  `11`  `12`
  <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1    75     1     0     0     1     3     3     0     0     0     0
2    80     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     1`
```

Comment: I dont think the linked duplicate is very clear for your purposes - try using `values_fill` from `tidyr::pivot_wider()` - something like `df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = Morphotype.ID, values_from = freq, values_fill = 0)` and see if that works. Good luck!

Comment: Worked perfectly!
Thank you very much!